# Referencing classes from an VC++ .EXE project from a unit tests .EXE project

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++

I've got an old legacy C++ app that I'm trying to write some unit tests for.  I've created a second project in my solution that builds to a unit testing executable (using googletest). The test project references the header files from the main project.  The test project builds fine until I try and use one of the classes from the main project.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "JsContext.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(JsContextTests, CreateJsContext) {
  JsContext context; // linking fails as soon as this line is added
}
```

Produces..

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall JsContext::JsContext(void)" (??0JsContext@@QAE@XZ)    JsContextTests.obj  tests
Error   2   fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals D:\Projects\Js-Clean\src\Debug\tests.exe    tests
```

The main executable doesn't produce a .lib file so I'm unsure what I should be linking the test project against.

What's the best approach to unit testing classes from another EXE project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your main project doesn't produce a library, you need to link against the `.obj` file generated from `JsContext.cpp`, or whichever file has the source for `JsContext.h`. However, it should be trivial to change your main project to build into a static library, instead of executable. You can do this in the Project Properties, under **Configuration -> General -> Configuration Type**.

If building a static library isn't possible, I think your best choice would probably be to just recompile the source files in your test project; you could add a 'Main Project Dependencies' filter and only include the source files needed for what you're testing.

If that's not possible, as a last resort, you may be able to use a pre-link event to copy the relevant `.obj` files from the main project's output directory to your test project's output directory, but I wouldn't suggest this.